# How to check that remote driver has not quit? (Python, Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need a method to check if a remote driver has quit or not. There're a lot of ways to do so with normal drivers like chrome:

```
  if not driver.service.is_connectable():
        break
```

But, since remote does not have service it becomes a problem. So, could you help me, please? :)

Comment: by quitting you mean terminating the service? if yes then you can test if remote port is available. so if it is not there is really high probability it has been terminated.

Comment: @AlexeyR. but how do I check if the remote port is not available in code?